# Delphi, at design-time, what is the state of ComponentState, ControlState when created with a nil owner?

Tags: delphi, pascal

If a function is executed at design-time, and creates a TComponent / TControl descendant with a nil owner, the following code in System.Classes will not call InsertComponent:

```
constructor TComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FComponentStyle := [csInheritable];
  if AOwner <> nil then AOwner.InsertComponent(Self);
end;
```

As such, our new object will not inherit ComponentState.
What happens to conditions that rely on the csDesigning flag for this component?

```
if csDesigning in ComponentState
```

Comment: Ask yourself if the component that you create at runtime is ever created at design time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition would render `False`.

That means for you as component builder that when you apparently intentionally create a (sub-)component without an owner, any reliance on whether that component is being designed by an end user **simply should not exist**. If it does, you would have to implement a custom "is designing"-state system, but then you better should redesign your requirements.

For overriden components you could call the protected `SetDesigning` method yourself.

This all assumes that you are fully aware of creating designtime sub-components without owner generally should be prevented unless you have very compelling reasons not to. Remember that components on the component pallete always should follow the default owner-mechanism.

Comment: As far as I know none of Design-time components should be created without owner at all. Why? Without owner there is no guarantee that such component would be destroyed which could lead to Delphi IDE leaking memory because of that.

Comment: @SilverWarior It's not about the component itself, but about a sub-component within. At least that's what I make up of the question. Otherwise you are most definately right!

Comment: Yeah but same rules apply. Unless mentioned component is designed properly then there is no guarantee that mentioned sub-component will be ever destroyed. So relying on a component notification system that relies on Owner property and is implemented in base component classes is  much safer than hopping that component developer hasn't screwed up and forgot needed code to properly destroy all sub-components.

Comment: @NGLN yes, i was referring to a sub-component within the creation of a component at design-time.  It makes sense that this should be avoided when possible, thanks!